# Pass blocks with latex commands verbatim when converting from kramdown

Tags: latex, markdown, kramdown

This may be a trivial problem, but I could not find a solution. I need to translate a markdown file into LaTeX using `kramdown`.
However, in the `.md` file I have blocks of lines which has been already preprocessed, so that they contain LaTeX commands.

```
markdown text 
markdown text 
markdown text 
markdown text

\latexcommand
\latexcommand

markdown text
markdown text
```

Is it possible to tell `kramdown` to pass such lines verbatim (possibly by "marking" them in some way) when converting to LaTeX?

Comment: Have you looked at Kramdown's [Math Blocks](https://kramdown.gettalong.org/syntax.html#math-blocks)? If so, how do they fail to meet your needs?

Comment: I understand that math blocks put a math environment around my LaTeX commands, which I don't want. Am I wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

kramdown has [several extensions](https://kramdown.gettalong.org/syntax.html#extensions), one of them, `nomarkdown`, being a method for protecting content from the parser and passing the content directly to a converter.

Using your example:

```
markdown text·
markdown text·
markdown text·
markdown text

{::nomarkdown type="latex"}
\latexcommand
\latexcommand
{:/}

markdown text
markdown text
```

This will result in the following LaTeX output:

```latex
markdown text
markdown text
markdown text
markdown text

\latexcommand
\latexcommand

markdown text
markdown text
```

And this HTML output:

```html
<p>markdown text
markdown text
markdown text
markdown text</p>


<p>markdown text
markdown text</p>
```